Firebase Messaging Api : Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid credential
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/jsrsasign-all-min.js"></script>

function getAccessToken() {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      const key = {
        client_email: "firebase-adminsdk-lmaet@****.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        private_key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nKey\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
      };

      const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'];
      
      const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
      const payload = {
        iss: key.client_email,
        scope: SCOPES.join(' '),
        aud: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
        exp: now + 3600,
        iat: now
      };

      const header = {
        alg: 'RS256',
        typ: 'JWT'
      };

      const encodeBase64Url = (input) => {
        return btoa(JSON.stringify(input))
          .replace(/=/g, '')
          .replace(/\+/g, '-')
          .replace(/\//g, '_');
      };

      const encodedHeader = encodeBase64Url(header);
      const encodedPayload = encodeBase64Url(payload);

      const signContent = `${encodedHeader}.${encodedPayload}`;

      const pemToArrayBuffer = (pem) => {
        const base64 = pem
          .replace(/-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----/, '')
          .replace(/-----END PRIVATE KEY-----/, '')
          .replace(/\s/g, '');
        const binary = atob(base64);
        const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(binary.length);
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (let i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
          bytes[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return buffer;
      };

      const privateKeyArrayBuffer = pemToArrayBuffer(key.private_key);

      const privateKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
        'pkcs8',
        privateKeyArrayBuffer,
        {
          name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5',
          hash: { name: 'SHA-256' },
        },
        false,
        ['sign']
      );

      const encoder = new TextEncoder();
      const signatureArrayBuffer = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        { name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5' },
        privateKey,
        encoder.encode(signContent)
      );

      const encodedSignature = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(signatureArrayBuffer)))
        .replace(/=/g, '')
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')
        .replace(/\//g, '_');

      const jwt = `${signContent}.${encodedSignature}`;

      const response = await fetch('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
          grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
          assertion: jwt
        })
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (data.access_token) {
        resolve(data.access_token);
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Failed to obtain access token'));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}

async function sendNotification(token, tkid, serviceAccount) {
  try {
    const jwtToken = await getAccessToken(serviceAccount);

    const response = await fetch(
      "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/silent-fuze-42760-t5/messages:send",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: {
            token: token,
            notification: {
              title: "Profile View Alert",
              body: "Someone viewed your profile. Check now to see who viewed you!",
            },
            data: {
              tkid: tkid,
            },
          },
        }),
      }
    );

    const responseData = await response.json();
    console.log("Notification sent:", responseData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending notification:", error);
  }
}


I'm trying to authenticate with Firebase using a service account to send push notifications via Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). However, I'm encountering an authentication error when trying to obtain an access token.
Here's what I've done so far:

Created a service account in the Firebase Console for my project "silent-fuze-427608-t5".
Downloaded the private key JSON file for this service account.
Implemented a function to generate a JWT and exchange it for an access token using the OAuth 2.0 token endpoint.

I've verified that:

The service account email is correct: firebase-adminsdk-lmaet@silent-fuze-427608-t5.iam.gserviceaccount.com
The project ID is correct: silent-fuze-427608-t5
The necessary APIs (Firebase Cloud Messaging API, IAM API) are enabled in the Google Cloud Console
The service account has the "Firebase Admin SDK Administrator Service Agent" role


I've also tried generating a new private key, but the issue persists.

